# Prove that following polynomial has no non-zero real solution.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, number-theory, problem-solving

Prove that following equation has no non-zero real solution.
$$ \sum_{ 1 \leq n \leq 120,\, 2|n \;\textrm{or}\; 3|n } x^n = 0$$

Any idea?

Comment: This doesn't seem right..... Consider the following example:
$$ \sum_{ 1 \leq n \leq 6,\, 2|n \;\textrm{or}\; 3|n } x^n = 0$$ Then the equation becomes $x^2+x^3+x^4+x^6=0$.  But this is not the same as $(x^3+x^6)= -(x^2+x^4+x^6)$, you have to consider that some of the $n$ will be divisible by both $3$ and $2$ (like $6,12,18,24,...$ etc)

Comment: That is true. The highest power is even, but that does not make the whole function even. There is a summation sign. Didn't think about that. Took comment off

Comment: @Squirtle You're right. I just write that to express question in other language. I deleted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to see that we can rewrite the equation in the following forms
$$
 0 = \sum_{ 1 \leq n \leq 120,\, 6|n } x^n  + \sum_{ 1 \leq n \leq 120,\, 6|n-2 } x^n +\sum_{ 1 \leq n \leq 120,\, 6|n-3 } x^n +\sum_{ 1 \leq n \leq 120,\, 6|n-4 } x^n ,
$$
and
$$
 0 = x^2 ( 1 + x + x^2 + x^4  ) (1+\sum_{ 1 \leq n < 120,\, 6|n } x^n) .
$$
Now, note that 
$$ 1 + \sum_{ 1 \leq n < 120,\, 6|n } x^n  > 0$$
and (since $1 + x + x^2>0$)
$$ 1 + x + x^2 + x^4 > 0 $$
So
$$
 ( 1 + x + x^2 + x^4  ) \sum_{ 1 \leq n < 120,\, 6|n } x^n > 0 .
$$